# upload dataframes to s3 python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dataframe, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to divide the dataframe like below:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = """
A,B,C
87jg,28,3012
h372,28,3011
kj87,27,3011
2yh8,54,3010
802h,53,3010
5d8b,52,3010
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=',')

for key, group in df.groupby(['C','B']):
    group.to_csv(f'df_{key}.csv', index=False)
```

This would export the results of group by dataframes to local machine. Is there a way to perform this operation and upload these multiple split csv's to s3 (something like put_object of boto3)

Comment: then what you are expecting ?

Comment: make sure you have installed f3fs and call `df.to_csv('s3://my_bucket/dummy.csv', index=False)` pandas will "understand" you want to write the csv to s3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [s3fs](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) which you have to install as well. Installation can be done using `pip`, e.g.:

```
pip install s3fs
```

**Verified** example based on your code:

```
import os

from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import s3fs

# I did not use my default aws profile
# so had to provide key and secret. If you use
# the default aws profile, providing `key`
# and `secret` should not be required
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(
        anon=False,
        key='<access_key>',
        secret='<secret_key>')

data = """ 
A,B,C
87jg,28,3012
h372,28,3011
kj87,27,3011
2yh8,54,3010
802h,53,3010
5d8b,52,3010
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=',')

for key, group in df.groupby(['C','B']):
    group.to_csv(fs.open(f's3://<bucket-name>/df_{key[0]}-M{key[1]}.csv', 'w'), index=False)
```

The code **correctly uploads** the files:

[image]

Comment: @omdurg Sorry, I don't know what do you mean. You can update your question with the new format that you want if you want.

Comment: @omdurg I see. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import boto3


data = """
A,B,C
87jg,28,3012
h372,28,3011
kj87,27,3011
2yh8,54,3010
802h,53,3010
5d8b,52,3010
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=',')

client = boto3.client('s3')
for key, group in df.groupby(['C', 'B']):
    group.to_csv(f'df_{key}.csv', index=False)
    client.upload_file(f'df_{key}.csv', 'my-another-test-bucket-2',
                       f'df_{key[0]}-M{key[1]}.csv')
```

**S3 Bucket**

[image]

Comment: @omdurg Yeah, it's possible. I have updated answer with screenshot. Try it out.

Comment: `[Errno 30] Read-only file system:`? Didn't get your question. I would suggest to ask a fresh question(as this is marked as duplicate). Also let us know which answer worked for you for this particular question. You can upvote/accept provided answer. For the `Read-only` issue please ask another question providing all possible details.